# Finding $k^{th}$ smallest in row and column-wise sorted matrix $m\times n$

Tags: algorithms

Let $M$ be a $m\times n$, in which rows and columns of $M$ are sorted in increasing.

**Problem.**

Find $k^{th}$ smallest number in $O(m\log(mn))$.

**My attempts.**

I merge all rows in a single sorted array in time $O(mn\log(mn))$ but this idea isn't efficient and I think there is a solution with running time $O(m\log(mn))$. After many hours thinking about this problem, I found a solution with running time like $O(k\log(mn))$, so $k$ can be $O(mn)$, eventually, this gives us the bound $O(mn\log(mn))$.Anyone can give me some hints about how I can achieve my desired time complexity?

Comment: Please describe your solution with $O(k \log(mn))$ running time in the question.

Comment: @D.W. According to this link,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519223/comparing-two-different-ways-of-finding-the-kth-smallest-element-in-a-column-wis , it's sufficient to when we extract minimum from our heap that point to $M[i,j]$, we insert $M[i+1,j]$ and $M[i,j+1]$ in our heap. Thus, after $k$ times removing  minimum in our heap , we find out $k^{th}$ smallest in $O(k\log(mn))$.

Comment: @Jut, where did this required upper-bound came from? And how sure are you that such bound exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a $O(n)$ time solution](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eandy/pubs/X+Y.pdf). See discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233031/given-two-sorted-array-in-ascending-order-with-same-length-n-calculate-the-kth).

[1]: [Selection in X+Y and Matrices with Sorted Rows and Columns](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eandy/pubs/X+Y.pdf).  A. Mirzaian, E. Arjomandi, Information Processing Letters 20:13-17, 2 January 1985.

[2]: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233031/given-two-sorted-array-in-ascending-order-with-same-length-n-calculate-the-kth

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  We generally prefer that you provide a full citation/reference, so that the answer is still useful even if the link stops working.  I've edited your answer to add that in this case, but I wanted to let you know for the future.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in $O(n\log n)$ time.

As an example, consider the square matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$ where $M_{i,j} \leq M_{i+1,j}$ and $M_{i,j} \leq M_{i,j+1}$.

To visualise the solution, organise the matrix into a lattice.

[image: Depiction of the matrix in lattice form]

There is an edge $v_1v_2$ in the graph if it is known that $v_1 \leq v_2$. Labelling the bottom row of the lattice as the first, if $r \leq n$ then the $r^{\text{th}}$ row of the lattice contains the elements that sit between the $\frac{r(r-1)}{2}+1$ smallest element and the $\frac{r(r+1)}{2}$ smallest element.

Notice that if row $r$ of the lattice contains the $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest element and $r \leq n$ then

\begin{align*}
\frac{r(r-1)}{2}+1 &< k \leq \frac{r(r+1)}{2} \\
r-1 &< \frac{-1 + \sqrt{8 k + 1}}{2} \leq r
\end{align*}

If $r > n$ then notice that the $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest element is the $mn - k + 1^{\text{th}}$ largest element and use a similar formula for finding the row in the lattice.

So compare elements in row $\left\lceil \frac{-1 + \sqrt{8 k + 1}}{2} \right\rceil$ of the lattice and notice that a row in the lattice represents a diagonal in the original matrix.

A row in the lattice has at most $\min\{m,n\}$ squares. Assume WLOG that $m \leq n$. The $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest item can be found in $O(m\log m)$ time.

For non-square matrices, use a similar procedure but find a piece-wise expression to find the relevant row.To do this, make use of the fact that a diagonal of an $m\times n$ grid has at most $\min\{m, n\}$ elements.